# Prove that $(a, b) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A \cup B))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This seems simple enough, but it's my first time using the "formal" definition of ordered pair, which is that $(a, b) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$.

Prove: If $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, then $(a, b) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A \cup B))$ (where $\mathcal{P}(X)$ denotes the power set of $X$).

*Proof*: This is equivalent to showing that $(a, b) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$, or: $\forall x, \text{if } x \in (a, b) \rightarrow x \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$.

1. Let $x = \{a\}$. Then, since $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$ and $\{a\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, $\{a\} \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$.
2. Let $x = \{a, b\}$. Since $\{a, b\} \subseteq A \cup B$, by definition $\{a, b\} \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$.

Therefore, $(a, b) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A \cup B))$.

What I'm unsure about is whether I can just "step" through the elements as I did in the numbered list above. I figured since there are only 2 elements, it would be straightforward.

Comment: Yes you can, when you denote A={x,y} what you are really saying is that z is in A if, and only if, z=x or z=y, in a formal logical sense.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be OK but it seemed too "easy"